# Unable to create class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, build.gradle

I am using spring boot application for a project and getting the following error while running the project from jar using `java -jar build/libs/com.user.admin.rest.services.jar`. But its not a blocker and i was able to access the api's, and the logger is working fine as intended. I just want to resolve this error.

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory specified in jar:file:/Users/Samuel/UserMgmt/com.user.admin.rest.services/build/libs/com.user.admin.rest.services.jar!/META-INF/log4j-provider.properties
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.Provider.loadLoggerContextFactory(Provider.java:96)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:91)
    at com.user.admin.rest.services.api.UserServiceResource.<clinit>(UserServiceResource.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.user.admin.rest.services.api.Application.main(Application.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

I have added the following lines for logger in the build.gradle file.

`compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.8.2'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8.2'`

And my log4j2.xml file is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration status="ERROR" name="example-config">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="PATTERN">%-5level %d [%t] %c:%M(%L): %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Did you rebuild your Spring Boot executable jar?  Did you attempt to inspect the libraries included in the jar to verify that log4j is present there?

Comment: Yes, all the external dependencies required for this project is present in the libraries, even i have tried it with the previous version of the log4j and still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

> Generally speaking, you should never need to switch logging implementations; Logback should suit you fine. However, if you decide that you’d rather use Log4j or Log4j2, you’ll need to change your dependencies to include the appropriate starter for the logging implementation you want to use and to exclude Logback.
>   [Spring Boot in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-boot-in-action)

**Swapping out Logback for Log4j2 in Gradle**

1. Exclude the default logging

```
configurations {
  all*.exclude group:'org.springframework.boot',
               module:'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

2. Add Log4j2 logging

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
```

You can find details of *spring-boot-starter-log4j2* dependency version that is provided by Spring Boot [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).

Comment: I did exactly that. When I run `gradle dependencies`, I see `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` is in the list and `spring-boot-starter-logging` is not. When I run from IntelliJ, everything works fine.When I build a jar however using the Gradle Spring Boot plugin, I see the `ClassNotFoundException` in the question above. The class is present both in `/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.7.jar` and in `/BOOT-INF/classes`. I see logging, but logging pattern looks nothing like what I've defined in `log4j2.xml` and it's not using the appenders.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file? I just run a gradle project from Spring Initializr with the steps provided and got correct logging with no exceptions.

Comment: Found it, apparently Log4j2 completely ignores the system property `log4j.configurationFile` when there is no `log4j2.xml` on the classpath.

Comment: Stijn Van Bael, correct Log4j2 logging system requires the following customization files: log4j2.xml or log4j2-spring.xml. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration Do you think I should update the answer with this?

Answer (score 1):

I have met the similar problem. The version of `log4j-api` and `log4j-core` have to **match** (and `ClassNotFound` is a strange exception here). As you have said in comment, you have found `log4j-core-2.7.jar`, but I may guess your `log4j-api` is in version of **2.8.2** as your above description shows.

Check your dependency, remove old version of `log4j-core` and add new version should fix the problem.

Comment: Both libraries have version 2.7

Answer (score 0):

This exception is printed to `System.out` because the class is not on the classpath of Spring's boot loader. But this is not the cause of logging not working or not using the specified configuration file.

It's a Spring Boot Gradle plugin issue. It should add Log4j to the boot loader classpath when it detects a dependency on Log4j.